# Two Borel disjoint sets such that the perimeter of union is less than the sum of perimeters

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

**Exercise:** Find two Borel disjoint and bounded sets $E, F \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $\operatorname{Per}(E) + \operatorname{Per}(F) > \operatorname{Per}(E \cup F)$.

($\operatorname{Per}(A)$ is the perimeter of the set $A$).

**Attempt:** I can solve this without the request "disjoint", it's pretty easy, but not in the general case! I would pick two open squares of lenght 1 sharing a face, but I don't even know if the perimeter of an open set makes sense.

Comment: If you don't know the definition of "perimeter" for a Borel set, why are you asking this question?

Comment: @zhw That seems a good observation. As far as I know the perimeter is defined as the sup of $\int_E div \phi$, or as $|\partial E|(\mathbb R^n)$ where that is the measure derived from the theorem of structure of BVloc functions applied to $\chi_E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one dimension, $(0,1)\cup [1,2) = [0,2)$ is such an example: the perimeter of every interval is equal to $2$.

In higher dimensions $n>1$, multiply the above example by a cube $(0,1)^{n-1}$. The perimeter of a rectangular box is the same regardless of the box being open, closed, or half-closed: indeed, the [Caccioppoli definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caccioppoli_set#Caccioppoli_definition) of perimeter shows it is not affected by adding or removing a set of zero $n$-dimensional measure.